# nothing is displayed even where there is a password in the password field and the button is pressed

Tags: java

I am a new programmer in **bluej**. i tried using JPasswordField to accept a password .I added a button to submit the password. The problem is that nothing gets displayed even when the password is right or wrong.

I changed my code slightly to find the problem. I added an error message at the end. I added a check for equal length and equal characters in the final else . i added a message to be displayed when the button is pressed. i saved the sample password in the program itself in the form of a `char[]` .I made nearly all the variable into static  fields(so that they could be accessed by the object from outside).I even wrote the code for the `ActionListener actionPerformed() method`outside the main method.

This is my code.Sorry for pasting it entirely I couldn't identify the problematic part.
hint:You may overlook the parts I made for debugging(see above)

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class superb
{static char m[]={'h','i'};
static char z[]={' '};
static int w=0;
static char check;
static JButton j=new JButton("click me");
static  JPasswordField n=new JPasswordField();
public static void main()
    {Frame f=new Frame("hi");
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLayout(null);
f.add(n);
n.setBounds(100,200,100,200);
f.setSize(500,1000);
f.add(j);
j.setBounds(250,500,100,200);
j.setActionCommand("Sucesss");
j.addActionListener(abs);
j.setIcon(new ImageIcon("images1"));
System.out.println(z);
}
static ActionListener abs=new ActionListener()
{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E){
       String a=E.getActionCommand();
       if(a.equals("Sucesss") )
       {
           System.out.println("button pressed");
        z=n.getPassword();
        if(z.equals(m))
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sucessful");
          System.out.println("sucess button");  
        }
    }
    else
    {
     if(z.length==m.length)
     {System.out.println("Equal length");
      for(char c:z)
      {check= c;
       if(c==m[w])
       {w++;}
        }
        if(w==z.length)
        {
        System.out.println("Same Characters");
    System.out.println("error");
}
else
System.out.println("different characters");
}
     else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unequal length");
    }
}
    }
};
}
```

The problematic part I think might be the action listener

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E){
       String a=E.getActionCommand();
       if(a.equals("Sucesss") )
       {
           System.out.println("button pressed");
        z=n.getPassword();
        if(z.equals(m))
        {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sucessful");
          System.out.println("sucess button");  
        }
    }
    else
    {
     if(z.length==m.length)
     {System.out.println("Equal length");
      for(char c:z)
      {check= c;
       if(c==m[w])
       {w++;}
        }
        if(w==z.length)
        {
        System.out.println("Same Characters");
    System.out.println("error");
}
else
System.out.println("different characters");
}
     else{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unequal length");
    }
}
    }
};
```

m is the sample password
z is the accepted password
w is the variable that checks the password

The expected output should be

**System console**

```
button pressed
success button
```

![password field and button]

the actual output is

**System console**

```
button pressed
```

![password field and button]

Comment: Sorry, but your code is unreadable. Use your IDE to format it correctly. Change all your variable names to words that mean something.

Comment: Remember: for every second you "save" by using a single char variable name, you pay 10 seconds wondering when reading it later on "what was thing again?" And that is when you come back after a day. After a week, you will be as lost as the readers here.

Comment: Also note: the editor you are using to write your code isnt important to your question. Only use tags that really relate to your topic!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are trying to compare two objects that are arrays of characters. You might better use

`if (Arrays.equals(z, m)) ...`

**Documentation says:**

> **public static boolean equals(char[] a,
>                char[] a2)**
>
> Returns true if the two specified arrays of chars are equal to one
>   another. Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the
>   same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in
>   the two arrays are equal. In other words, two arrays are equal if they
>   contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array
>   references are considered equal if both are null.

Comment: Let's consider what you say yet there should be the error message displayed as i have typed in my program